# Django: form to query database

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, django-queryset

I want a user to be able to perform the following query:

*Fetch all the people, without Phd, with full time contract with a contract within two dates.*

that translates in Django:

```
Contract.objects.filter(
    person__is_doctor = False,
    type_contract = 'full',
    starting_date__gte = start_date,
    ending_date__lte = end_date
    )
```

How can I make a form/view/template to allow the user enter both *start_date* and *end_date* and show the results?

**models**

```
class Person(models.Model):
        name    = models.CharField(max_length=32)
        surname = models.CharField(max_length=32)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=32)
        is_doctor  = models.NullBooleanField(blank=True, verbose_name=_(u"Phd?")

TYPE_CONTRACT = (
    ('PT', 'Partial time'),
    ('FC', 'Full contract')
    )           

class Contract(models.Model):
        person        = models.ForeignKey(Person) #person hired
        type_contract = models.CharField(max_length = 9, blank = True, choices = TYPE_CONTRACT)
        starting_date = models.DateField(blank = True, null = True)
        ending_date   = models.DateField(blank = True, null = True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would refactor the `Contract` model to better encapsulate the choices, and also, why would a contract allow null values for the start and end dates? That seems odd to me from a business logic standpoint.

```
class Contract(models.Model):
    PT = 'Part Time'
    FC = 'Full Contract'
    CONTRACT_CHOICES = (
        ('PT', PT),
        ('FC', FC)
    )
    person        = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    type_contract = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=CONTRACT_CHOICES,
        default=PT)
    starting_date = models.DateField()
    ending_date   = models.DateField()

# view

from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ContactForm

def filter_contracts(request):
    form = ContractForm(request.POST or None)
    contracts = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            # encapsulating the contract values means you don't have to
            # hand-code them in the query so your code stays DRY
            contracts = Contract.objects.filter(person__is_doctor=False,
                type_contract=Contract.FC,
                starting_date__gte=form.cleaned_data.get('starting_date'),
                ending_date__lte=form.cleaned_data.get('ending_date'))
            # you might want to specify an order_by here
    return render(request, 'your_template.html', {'form': form,
        'contracts': contracts})

# template

<form action="." enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post">
    <ol>
        {{ form.as_ul }}
    </ol>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">Search</button>

    {% if contracts %}
    <table>
        {% for contract in contracts %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ contract.person }}</td>
            <td>{{ contract.type_contract }}</td>
            <td>{{ contract.starting_date }}</td>
            <td>{{ contract.ending_date }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

Comment: Ok, I've deleted my answer since the semantics are the same but quality isn't.

Comment: No need to delete your answer. It's good for people to see the differences between them.

Comment: @Brandon  First of all, thanks. I'm having problems when I edit url.py . `NameError at /admin/db_personal/query/
global name 'ContractForm' is not defined
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/db_personal/query/
Django Version: 1.7c1
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value: 
global name 'ContractForm' is not defined`

Comment: You just need to import the form class in the view. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @Brandon But, do I need to create a form?

Comment: If you want to persist the form data.

Answer (score 0):

This is the main idea, additionally you will have to check if start_date and end_date are actually in cleaned_data and take that into account when using filter().

**form**

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    start_date = forms.DateField(initial=datetime.date.today)
    end_date = forms.DateField(initial=datetime.date.today)
```

**view**

```
def my_view(request):
    contracts = Contract.objects.filter(person__is_doctor=False, type_contract='full')
    # if this is a POST request take start_date and end_date into account
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            contracts = contracts.filter(starting_date__gte=form.cleaned_data.get('start_date'), ending_date__lte=form.cleaned_data.get('end_date'))
    else:
        form = MyForm()
    # do everything else that you need to do before returning a response
    return render_to_response('template.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**template**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

{% for contract in contracts %}
    {{ contract.person }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question: *Tell me all the people, without Phd, with full time contract with a contract among two dates.*, and what's up with the `render_to_response` call? Still using Django 1.2?

Comment: I thought this: **How could I make a form/view/template to allow the user enter both start_date and end_date and show the results?** was the actual question. And the code is from Django 1.7

Comment: This allows the user to fill out the form, but where's the results? Not to be rude, but your view code is way out of date.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Could you point out what in my view is out of date? Thanks

Comment: Take a look at my answer for an example. There's no need for the extra if statement to instantiate the form with post data for one, and we haven't had to manually construct the `RequestContext` for a long time. Using `locals()` is ok if you have a couple of variables being passed to the template, but be careful using that with a lot of variables.