# Export data from a form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I needed an user enter some dates in order to make a query to the database with those dates so I followed [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28719354/4224819) steps and now is working properly. What I'd want is, apart of showing the data from the response, be able to export that data to a file. To do so I've made a form but I don't know how to continue.

My question is, where could I consult documentation about how to export from a form?

**views**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ContactForm

def filter_contracts(request):
    form = ContractForm(request.POST or None)
    contracts = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
                contracts = Contract.objects.filter(person__is_doctor=False,
                type_contract=Contract.FC,
                starting_date__gte=form.cleaned_data.get('starting_date'),
                ending_date__lte=form.cleaned_data.get('ending_date'))

    return render(request, 'your_template.html', {'form': form,
        'contracts': contracts})
```

**forms**

```
class ContractForm(forms.Form):

    starting_date    = forms.DateField()
    ending_date       = forms.DateField()
```

**template**

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls admin_static admin_modify %}

{% block content %}
<form action="." enctype="db_personal/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="POST">>
    <ul>
        {{ form.as_ul }}
    </ul>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
    <br> 
    <hr>
    {% if contracts %}
    <table border ="1" cellspacing="0">
        <th>Person</th>
        <th>Contract type</th>
        <th>Starting date</th>
        <th>Ending date</th>
        {% for contract in contracts %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ contract.person }}</td>
            <td>{{ contract.type_contract }}</td>
            <td>{{ contract.starting_date }}</td>
            <td>{{ contract.ending_date }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    {% endif %}
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: please clarify what you intend to do. If your code in the view has access to the form data entered by the user, then just save it to a file...

Comment: @Pynchia The point is how to join my [view](http://pastebin.com/1bSzP3WX) with a button with somethink like [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/outputting-csv/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to return your queryset results as something other than HTML, just have your view return the data in the appropriate format of your choice -- this could be csv, xml, json, yaml or just plain text.

See this example in the Django documentation on how to export csv data:

- [Outputting CSV with Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/outputting-csv/)

The Django docs also has a page how to export a PDF:

- [Outputting PDFs with Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/outputting-pdf/)

In your view -- after you process the form and query the database -- you should set the response's content-type so the browser will know what type of data it's expecting. Your formatted data will go into the response body. Most browsers can only show HTML or plain text, and maybe XML, but anything else they will just download as a file to the user's computer.

#### Example Code to Handle a "Download" Button

**Step 1**

In your `forms.py`, add an additional form to handle the "download" button:

```
from django import forms

class ContractForm(forms.Form):
    starting_date    = forms.DateField()
    ending_date       = forms.DateField()

class DownloadForm(forms.Form):
    starting_date = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    ending_date = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
```

This form contains 2 hidden fields -- for `starting_date` and `ending_date`. We will populate these fields based on the initial search query parameters.

**Step 2**

In your `views.py`, add code to render the `DownloadForm` (as a button):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ContractForm, DownloadForm

def filter_contracts(request):
    form = ContractForm(request.POST or None)
    contracts = None
    download_form = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            starting_date = form.cleaned_data.get('starting_date')
            ending_date = form.cleaned_data.get('ending_date')
            contracts = Contract.objects.filter(person__is_doctor=False,
                                                type_contract=Contract.FC,
                                                starting_date__gte=starting_date,
                                                ending_date__lte=ending_date)
            # Create the DownloadForm instance here so you can pass it in the
            # context dict.
            download_form = DownloadForm(initial={
                'starting_date': starting_date,
                'ending_date': ending_date
            })

    return render(request, 'your_template.html',
                  {
                      'form': form,
                      'contracts': contracts,
                      'download_form': download_form
                  })
```

When instantiating the `DownloadForm`, the view sets the `starting_date` and `ending_date` as initial parameters to the form so when the template renders it, it will contain the query parameters in the hidden fields. (You can use your browser to confirm this.)

**Step 3**

Now, modify your template to add the `Download` button form (this is the `DownloadForm` instance you added to the view in the step above):

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls admin_static admin_modify %}

{% block content %}

<form action="." enctype="db_personal/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="POST">
    <ul>
        {{ form.as_ul }}
    </ul>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
    <br> 
    <hr>
    {% if contracts %}
    <table border ="1" cellspacing="0">
        <th>Person</th>
        <th>Contract type</th>
        <th>Starting date</th>
        <th>Ending date</th>
        {% for contract in contracts %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ contract.person }}</td>
            <td>{{ contract.type_contract }}</td>
            <td>{{ contract.starting_date }}</td>
            <td>{{ contract.ending_date }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    {% endif %}
</form>

{% if download_form %}
<form action="{% url 'download_data' %}"  method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ download_form.as_p }}
    <p>
        <input type="submit" class="btn" name="submit" value="Download" />
    </p>
</form>
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Note that the form `action` for the download button uses a named url called `download_data`. You will have to add a new url rule to your `urls.py` to handle the download form submission (see the next step).

**Step 4**

Add a new rule to your `urls.py` to handle the download form submission. This will map to a new view we'll be creating to return the requested data in CSV format:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from .views import filter_contracts, download_data

urls = patterns(
    # url prefix
    '',

    # view to render search form
    url(r'^contracts/$', filter_contracts, name='search_contracts'),

    # view to handle data download
    url(r'^contracts/download/$', download_data, name='download_data')
)
```

You will have to adjust the url configuration rules according to what you already have set up. The above is just a guide and example.

**Step 5**

Now, add a couple of new views in your `views.py` to handle the download button submission and fetching of the data:

```
def get_csv_data(starting_date, ending_date):
    """
    Prepare data in csv format for download.
    * This is called by ``download_data`` to perform the query.
    * Do your query here and format the results as CSV using a csv
      writer or manually.
    * For this example, we're using some dummy data.
    """
    data = []
    num = 10
    for n in xrange(num):
        person = 'Person {}'.format(n + 1)
        type_contract = 'Some contract'
        start_date = starting_date
        end_date = ending_date
        data.append(', '.join([start_date, end_date, person, type_contract]))
    return '\n'.join(data)

def download_data(request):
    """
    Process a request to download data.
    * POST must contain 'starting_date' and 'ending_date'.
    """
    from django.http import HttpResponse

    try:
        assert request.method == 'POST'
        form = DownloadForm(request.POST)
        assert form.is_valid()
        starting_date = form.cleaned_data.get('starting_date')
        ending_date = form.cleaned_data.get('ending_date')
        assert starting_date and ending_date
        contracts = get_csv_data(starting_date, ending_date)
        assert contracts
    except AssertionError:
        error = 'Your request has some problems.'
        contracts = error

    attachment = 'contract_data.csv'
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename="{}"'.format(attachment)
    response.write(contracts)
    return response
```

The `get_csv_data` function above is just an example to prepare some dummy data for testing. You should put your database query code there to fetch the queryset you need and then format the data as CSV. (The example function formats the dummy data manually but you should use the `csv` module to prepare your data -- see the Django example at the beginning of this answer for the link).

**Summary**

The basic idea is that:

- When you render the contract search results from a query, you just add an additional `DownloadForm` instance to the page. This shows up only as a `Download` button, but it contains hidden fields for the `starting_date` and `ending_date`.
- When the user clicks on the `Download` button, the form gets submitted to a new view called `download_data` that examines the `request.POST` dict and extracts the `starting_date` and `ending_date`. Then, it prepares the queryset data and renders it in CSV format.
- The `download_data` view then returns the response as an attachment with content-type `text/csv`. The user's browser will handle that as a download file automatically.

There's minimal error and security checking in the code, but this should get you started.

Comment: But what if I want both functionalities, show the results and export to a csv.

Comment: Personally, I would separate the functionalities into 2 operations. That makes the code easier to read and maintain. You can have a simple button on the frontend for "download results" for example, and use a view that queries the result and returns a response with formatted data (in csv for example). I.e., let the user decide if he/she wants just to look at the data in HTML format or download it. Some may not want to have a file download every time they perform a query. In other words, I would opt for simplicity first than to have the code perform multiple operations at once.

Comment: As far I know, an http response object can only have one content type -- you can't return both an HTML page and a csv file at the same time and have the browser display the page *and* download the file. They have to be 2 separate responses.

Comment: Yes, that's what I need. Show the data and then with another button export to a file, but once the data have been already shown. But I don't know how to relate a button with the exportation function and export the data previously filtered.

Comment: What you can do is, when you display the results for a query, also render a form to "download" -- and attach a hidden field to the form so you can embed the original query parameters. That way, when the user clicks on the download, you will get a, say, "query" field in your form that you can use to relookup the query and then return the results in a csv format. That's probably the simplest way and it will work as a start. You will end up doing 2 queries -- one for the original lookup and one for the download. But that's OK because they are or can be considered separate operations.

Comment: Then, if you want to optimize that, you can cache the query results from the existing lookup and if the user wants to download it from the HTML page, you can fetch the results from the cache and return it. But that will make your code more complex, of course. I would start with the simple first and make sure it works. Only then think about optimizing.

Comment: Thanks but no idea how to accomplish it

Comment: Can you post the form and view you're using to query the data and return the response? I can show you an example or with some pseudo-code to handle the "download" step to  extend from what you have.

Comment: Done, I've added it in the main post  ;)